# JavaScript this issue with parent and child classes/objects

Tags: javascript

I'm not quite sure how to explain it in words so here is some example code to show what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function carFactory(){
    this.wheelsPerCar = 4;

    this.car = function() {
        this.wheels = [];
        this.addWheels = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.wheelsPerCar; i++){
                var wheel = new this.wheel();
                this.wheels.push(wheel);
            }
        };

        this.wheel = function(){
        };
    };
};

var cf = new carFactory();
var myCar = new cf.car();
myCar.addWheels();
```

When I print myCar.wheels I get an empty array back. I think this is because this.wheelsPerCar is out of scope. I think I'm likely designing this completely wrong as I haven't work much with JavaScript classes and objects.

Answer (score 3):

You're kind of right. `wheelsPerCar` is not on the car, it's on the factory.

You could just change `this.wheelsPerCar = 4;` to be `var wheelsPerCar = 4;` then just use `wheelsPerCar` without `this` and it will be in scope.

Comment: It would also be better to pass the value in, otherwise all cars will have 4 wheels. ;-)

Comment: That's true. But that sounds messy. I think at that point you'd want prototypical inheritance instead

Answer (score 0):

The `carFactory` instance and the `car` instance don't have a parent-child relationship. They're defined together, but there's no class inheritance there.

You could expose the `wheelsPerCar` property to the inner `car` instance in 2 ways:

1. Pass an instance of `carFactory` to the `car` constructor function.
2. Set a `var wheelsPerCar = this.wheelsPerCar` variable in the `car` scope so it can access it without the `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.addWheels = function(){
     debugger;
     for(var i = 0; i < this.wheelsPerCar; i++){
         var wheel = new this.wheel();
         this.wheels.push(wheel);
     }
};
```

this.wheelsPerCar is undefined, 0 < undefined, evaluate as false. You want to read this [Scope and this in JavaScript](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) first. Also, you should be able to debug this with any browser.